# I am trying to figure out why List.ContainsAll doesn't work in Power Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I have a simple dataframe here.

[image]

I wrote a List.ContainsAll  -

`List.ContainsAll({[Numbers]},{1,2,3,4,5})`

why is it returning FALSE under the Custom column?

I have already wrapped the [Numbers] column in {} to make it a list already. What is the problem?

Comment: Because `[Numbers]` returns the value for the current row, i.e. only one of the numbers, not all of them. Thus it does not contain all the numbers, but only one.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was suspecting. In cases like this - how do I convert the {1,2,3,4,5} to a List inside a cell? I am thinking if I can convert that, I can run a simple List.ContainsAll and it should return TRUE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to reference an entire column rather than a single value.

To do this, prepend the table name you want to reference in front of the column name like this:

```
List.ContainsAll(#"Previous Step Name"[Numbers], {1,2,3,4,5})
```