# How to Perform Row-by-Row List Operations in Power Query

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I'm trying to compare CSVs from one column with CSVs in another column in the same row in Power Query. I need to ensure that all the CSVs in one column are in the other.

I tried using `List.ContainsAll`, but it seems like the syntax I'm using is not working. [The solution shared here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64753879/i-am-trying-to-figure-out-why-list-containsall-doesnt-work-in-power-query) is very close to what I need, but it's comparing all values in a column, not the cell's values.
Here is my sample code, but I think [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIkuY.jpg) explains the parent-child columns better. This picture shows [another scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jOAI.jpg) where the function also needs to work.

`Table.AddColumn(#"Replaced Value", "Contractual and Technical Types Match?", each List.ContainsAll({[Technical Turbine Type]},{[Contractual Turbine Type]}))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say your column contains a list but your image is not showing a list. Your image is showing text with commas separating them. This is what a list looks like

[image]

Assuming you really have columns of comma separated text, this ensures that everything in the **Contractual Turbine Type** column is also in the **Technical Turbine Type** column

Add custom column with formula

```
= List.ContainsAll(        
    List.Transform(Text.Split([Technical Turbine Type],","), each Text.Trim(_)),
    List.Transform(Text.Split([Contractual Turbine Type],","), each Text.Trim(_))
    )
```

You could just use this if you are not worried about spaces after the commas

```
= List.ContainsAll(        
    Text.Split([Technical Turbine Type],","),
    Text.Split([Contractual Turbine Type],",")
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for that tip! That doesn't quite work though because the "Contractual Turbine Type" could also be a list. I added a picture of another, equally valid entry.
In addition to being a list, the child values can be in any order, which is why I was trying to use the List.ContainsAll function.

Comment: Edited based on comment

Comment: That worked! Thanks for clarifying the difference between a list and just comma-separated text. I was assuming Power Query treated the two the same.